# How can make the height of my grid container square shaped depending on the size of the screen?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to create a grid with 3 columns and 3 rows (9 cells in total). I want the grid to be square shaped irrespective of device size (responsive).

**Ideal Grid I need:**

[image: Ideal Grid I need]

I have achieved the above grid in my laptop screen, but when I test it in mobile or other devices, my grid cells are turning rectangular.

**Rectangular grid in mobile:**

[image: Rectangular grid in mobile]

How can I keep them to be a square?

Here is my code. I have a flex container which takes 80vh height (The remaining 20vh is for header and footer). In the flex container, i have my grid container and each item in my grid is again a flex item.

Here is my code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.grid-wrapper {
  height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.grid-gameboard-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  min-height: 50vh;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  min-width: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div class='grid-gameboard-container'>
    <div class="grid-item">1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">3</div>
    <div class="grid-item">4</div>
    <div class="grid-item">5</div>
    <div class="grid-item">6</div>
    <div class="grid-item">7</div>
    <div class="grid-item">8</div>
    <div class="grid-item">9</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting row size? Something like: `grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 100px);` Alternatively, you could remove `min-height` and set `height` on grid items.

Comment: You're using *viewport percentage heights* (`vh`) to size the items. This means that your item heights are based on the height of the screen. Mobile screens are relatively taller (more vertical) than laptop screens. That's what you're seeing. Consider using another unit of length, such as `%` or `px`.

Comment: In short, by using `vh` or `vw` or any other viewport percentage unit, your container size and shape is tied to the size and shape of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your css .grid-item section or in the .grid-gameboard-container section if you want it to grow with mobile responsive behavior.

```
aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
```